# Retaining and naming user-inputted variables in C

Tags: c, math

I am trying to calculate a gradient using several X and Y values. My problem is that after my code takes the mean of the X and Y values I cannot re-use the user-inputted X and Y values to further calculate a gradient as I don't know how to name them. I've included my code below, and I think I have to use either Arrays or Global variables for this task.

Thank you in advance, my coding knowledge is limited.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
int n, i;
float num[1000], total=0, mean;

printf("Enter the amount of x-values:");
scanf("%d", &n);
while (n <= 0 || n > 1000) {
    printf("Print error. The number should in range of 0 to 1000.\n");
    printf("Please try to enter the amount again: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d. Input x-value:", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &num[i]);
    total += num[i];
}
mean=total/n;
printf("The mean of all the x-values entered is %.2f to 2 decimal places", mean);

{
    float num[1000], total=0, mean;

    printf("Enter the amount of y-values:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n <= 0 || n > 1000) {
        printf("Print error. The number should in range of 0 to 1000.\n");
        printf("Please try to enter the amount again: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d. Input y-value:", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &num[i]);
        total += num[i];
    }
    mean = total / n;
    printf("The mean of all the y-values entered is %.2f to 2 decimal places", mean);

    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you use 2 different arrays for X and Y, say numX and numY ? Also check the scope of the variable num[] when you define it the second time. This 1) hides the outer num[] variable in this scope and 2) is not available for use outside this scope. Perhaps you don't want that?

Comment: @s_b thank you for your advice, I have now changed my code to have two separate arrays. However I am a bit confused by what you mean by changing the scope of arrays, I have just read up on them so I'm not very knowledgeable on the matter. I think I need to limit the visibility but I'm unsure

Comment: yes, scope and visibility are interchangeable in this case. When I say you need to check the scope of your second array, I am looking at the second float num[] you have defined inside a pair of parenthesis and thinking : "hmm, this will no longer be available when the parenthesis closes; and you haven't even calculated the gradient yet. " I don't think this is what you want, do you?

Comment: @s_b okay I think I have fixed it with my computing lecturer, my only problem now is naming x0 and y0 (the first values from the numx[1000] and numy[1000] array). How would I go about this?

Comment: Why do you need to name them ? By they way, they are already 'named' as numx[0] and numy[0]. So if you need another name, you can always define new variables and assign numx[0] and numy[0] to them.